# CSS intellinsense stop working on php extension files

Tags: php, css, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I can´t use intellisense with bootstrap css in html tags when files has php extension. That's was working well until the last upgrade from visual studio code.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks!.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
After severall error/test i found that this has to add to settings.json:
 "css.styleSheets": [
        "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css",
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"    
    ],
    "css.enabledLanguages": [
        "html",
        "php"
    ]
```

Then restart vscode.

Problem solve.